# Form automatically reset after .hide function

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I use this [jquery tabs](http://www.jacklmoore.com/demo/tabs.html) as a backbone to my tabs. Inside those tabs is a form with no submit action, but when I change tabs, each form value is erased. How can I disable reset on those forms?

In addition, I load the form by `.append()` before it shown.

Problem solved, I use `.exist()` function to prevent it reappend if already shown.

Comment: if you do `.append()` I am confident that for 100% chance the form data will reset

Comment: but i only use `.(append)` on first load, on tabs change i use the default by hiding it.

Comment: I guess you can show an example using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)!

Comment: We could help better if you showed us your code